# How can I solve document is not defined error?

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error I thought I would be because of the node.js but I am not sure of it. How can I solve it ?

```
[Running] node "c:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\projectjs\index.js"
c:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\projectjs\index.js:1
var counter = document.getElementById("count-el")
              ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\projectjs\index.js:1:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

```js
var counter = document.getElementById("count-el")
var count = 0 

function increment() {
    count = count + 1
    counter.innerText = count
}
```

```html
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>People entered:</h1>
            <h2 id="count-el">0</h2>
            <button id="increment-btn" onclick="increment">INCREMENT</button>
        </div>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: node.js does not have a window object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript is designed to be embedded in an HTML document, loaded by a `<script>` element and executed by a web browser.

It is not designed to run in Node.js which isn't centred around documents at all.

Open the HTML document in a web browser. It already has a `<script>` element.